# What does 'fully excited' actually mean?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, terminology, atomic-physics, definition, degrees-of-freedom

In statistical mechanics you often hear the phrases such as 'when the degrees of freedom are fully excited then....'. An example would be the validity of the equipartition theorem. But what is the technical definition of a fully excited state/degree of freedom?